# Can we create a TreeView with checkboxes in WPF without data binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I was just wondering that can we create a treeview in WPF without data binding?

Comment: search for your problem before posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually declare your items in the xaml.

```
  <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Margin="17,38,0,63" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="238">
        <TreeView.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform AngleY="0.567"/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="0.495"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TreeView.RenderTransform>
        <CheckBox Content="Item 1"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Item 2"/>
    </TreeView>
```